# Is it possible to substitute pure html and js for JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I'm learning JavaEE now and I kind of feel that JSP can be messy... I hate to mix my Java code with HTML... I want to separate the front end view and Java code as much as possible.

I've ever tried Twitter Bootstrap and I find it amazing. Is there any way that I can use HTML and JS(maybe some framework like Bootstrap) to substitute for JSP view technique? How should I accomplish the data interaction?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is what all the kids are doing. You use REST.

You can see an example of just that in this [Quickstart](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/kitchensink-html5-mobile).

Comment: Thanks! What do you think can be the disadvantages of the way I mentioned?

Comment: I think that some people have a hard time transitioning to different technologies.  REST functions different then JSP.  A lot of Java programmers don't like JavaScript. So if you are working with someone like that then that may be a disadvantage. Personally I like to keep my HTML separate from my logic.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, no.  JSP is a server-side technology.  That means that the code you write in the page is executing on your server in the environment you have set up there.  HTML and JavaScript are client-side technologies; the code you write in these languages executes in the web browser of the people viewing your website.  Neither technology is a complete replacement for the other; both are needed.

Even if you move more of functionality out of JSP into JavaScript (a "heavy client" implementation), you still need some server technology for your JavaScript to call to.  You could get rid of JSP by moving some of the server functionality into other technologies: webservices (JAX-WS, Axis, etc.), RESTful services (JAX-RS, ApacheCXF, etc.), or straight up synchronous web-pages.  But the point is regardless of what you use or whether you get rid of JSP entirely, you still need a server-side technology.